# maas, landscape autopilot juju add tagged vlan provider?

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

I have a 5 server setup with a single interface (tagged) on MAAS The default route is a cisco switch with a trunked interface and native vlan17 (for pxe boot) (172.17.17.0/24).

2 of the 5 servers two trunked interfaces with native vlan 17, and the other three have a single interface, trunked with native vlan 17.

All of my physical servers have been deployed on this network (172.17.17.0/24), all of the juju components also have been deployed on this network.

The provider and tenant networks were create as admin_net 10.10.0.0/16 and ext_net as 172.17.17.0/24.

All instances that are created work correctly and are able to ping to the outside world, instances with a floating IP address are accessible via the floating ip address. Everything appears to be working correctly.

So now what I want to do is add additional tagged provider networks on VLAN10 and VLAN11 and I am totally stumped on how to do it.

Can anyone assist?

thanks